# How can I upgrade rails 2 find with conditions to rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
 find_by_formname_and_language_id('error', varLanguage, :conditions => ['fieldnumber = ?', varError])
```

> I am upgrading an old rails application.can someone please let me know how can we write this in rails 4?
>   As per the request this is Translation model

```
Translation id: nil, language_id: 0, formname: nil, fieldname: nil, fieldnumber: 0, created_at: nil, token: "", translated: nil, checked: false, sitacode: nil, ttype: 0
```

Comment: Can you please add your model to your question (using the `edit` link below the tags). And explain what the `conditions` clause is meant to do?

Comment: the conditioning is finding field number by the parameter as per the code I guess

Comment: The most reliable way to upgrade your queries is to watch real SQL result of the old expression (Rails2) and then construct new expression to return exact same SQL query.

Comment: So, when the old expression produces a query like `SELECT ... WHERE fromname = ... AND language_id = ... AND fieldnumber = ...`, you have to do something like `Translation.find_by(formname: 'error', language_id: varLanguage, fieldnumber: varError)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming:

- `varLanguage` holds a `language_id`
- `varError` holds a `fieldnumber`

Then it seems it ought to be something like:

```
Translation.find_by(formname: 'error', language_id: varLanguage, fieldnumber: varError)
```

You might want to take a look at the [ruby style guide](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=ruby+style+guide&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8). `formname`, `varLanguage`, `fieldnumber`, and `varError` are all unconventional names. By convention, they should be `form_name`, `var_language`, `field_number`, and `var_error`.

Also, I would think `var_language` should actually be `language_id`. And `var_error` should be `field_number`. In which case it would look more like:

```
Translation.find_by(form_name: 'error', language_id: language_id, field_number: field_number)
```

But, some of that would require you to make changes to your model, which might be more work than it's worth.

Comment: Thanks, I know the style we use but its an old project and will need update it

Comment: I feel your pain... Good luck!